# About mechanism of setting object property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to Spring-MVC and I am confused about the mechanism of setting object property and mechanism of passing object between requests. So this is an example.
I have a class named `Person` to store information with two fields name and age. And I have a controller class named `PersonController` below.

```java
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView enterInfo() {
        return new ModelAndView("home", "command",new Person());
    }
    @RequestMapping("/next")
    public String getInfo(Person per, Model md) {
        md.addAttribute("name", per.getName());
        md.addAttribute("age", per.getAge());
        return "next";
    }

}
```

The first method `enterInfo()` return the `ModelAndView` object which references to view named "home", and also create a new empty `Person` object. And this is my `home.jsp` file:

```html
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "next">
        Name: <input type = "text" name = "name"/><br><br>
        Age: <input type = "text" name = "age"/><br><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I click "submit" button, the Spring will map to the `@RequestMapping("/next")` which is annotated method `getInfo()`. This method return the view "next" which shows information about the person object.

The project runs very well , but I don't know how Spring can run it without error. In the both methods of controller class I don't have any setting methods. And also in the method `getInfo()`, how does Spring get the exactly Person object I have just created ? I think without annotation like `@ModelAttribure` or `@SessionAttribute`, the method `getInfo()` cannot get the object `Person` and therefore it will be null. But in this example it still can get the information. So anyone can explain me about this mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

*And also in the method getInfo(), how does Spring get the exactly Person object I have just created.*

It doesn't. It creates a new instance.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods

> **Any other argument**
>
> If a method argument is not matched to any of the earlier values in
>   this table [e.g. @ModelAttribute] and it is a simple type (as determined by
>   BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty, it is a resolved as a @RequestParam.
>   **Otherwise, it is resolved as a @ModelAttribute**.

So it is effectively a `@ModelAttribute` and as the docs note in relation to this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

> You can use the @ModelAttribute annotation on a method argument to
>   access an attribute from the model or **have it be instantiated if not
>   present**.

So if you wanted to ensure that the same Person was referenced on load and on edit it would need to be somehow in the model e.g. in the session. More typically you might load from a database so you could write a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` and your controller would look like:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping("/loadPersonForEdit")
    public String loadPersonForEdit() {
        return "edit";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/updatePerson")
    public String updatePerson(Person per) {
        //database update person
        return "personDetails";
    }

    //called by the framework on loadPersonForEdit() to set the model attribute
    //on saving the edit, the returned instance will be used passed to updatePerson()
    @ModelAttribute("person")
    public Person getPerson(@RequestParam(value = "personId", required = false) 
                                   Long personId){
       return personId == null ? new Person() : datebase.getPerson(personId);    
    }
}
```